# Create collection if it does not exists

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a collection if it does not exists in firestore.

My code is the following

```
 val docRef = fbase.collection("cities").document("LA")
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            document ->
        if(document!= null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else{
            FireBaseRepository 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

The 'FireBaseRepository' is just a class with an init to initialize the collection. My code always passes through the if condition because of the class FirebaseFirestore.java which makes sure that the collection cannot be null. I have already looked on the recommended links  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=en.

```
 @NonNull
  public CollectionReference collection(@NonNull String collectionPath) {
    checkNotNull(collectionPath, "Provided collection path must not be null.");
    ensureClientConfigured();
    return new CollectionReference(ResourcePath.fromString(collectionPath), this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with the following code

```
        if(!document.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            FireBaseRepository
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```